# 3 Knights and Knaves

Tags: logic, recreational-mathematics

I have been struggling with this problem:

Knights always tell the truth but knaves never tell the truth. In a group of three
individuals (who we will label as N1, N2, and N3) each is either a knight or a knave. Each
makes a statement:

N1: “We are all three knaves.”

N2: “Two of us are knaves and one of us is a knight."

N3: “I am a knight and the other two are knaves.”

Which are knights and which are knaves? Explain your reasoning.

I think that N1 is a Knave because at least one of them should be a Knight, however I am not able to determine if the other two are Knights or Knaves, because I think that they could both be telling the truth, however that would lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Your reasoning for N1 is incorrect -- why should one of them be a knight?  Better reasoning is this: if N1 is a knight, then all three are knaves, which is a contradiction.  Hence N1 is a knave, and hence not all three are knaves.

Comment: Thank you vadim, I like this reasoning better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $N_3$ were a knight, then there are two knaves and a knight, but that would mean that $N_2$ tells the truth and hence he is a knight, which means that there are at least two knight or at most one knave. A contradiction. Hence $N_3$ is a knave. Clearly, $N_1$ is also a knave, for if he were a knight, then everybody would be a knave. A contradiction. Now as the first is a knave, then he lies, and hence not all of them are knaves and hence $N_2$ is a knight. Indeed, what $N_2$ says is consistent.

Comment: Thank you very much Yiorgos, that definitely cleared it up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more formal approach to this problem, and to similar ones. Let's write $\;T(x)\;$ for "$\;x\;$ speaks the Truth" or "$\;x\;$ is a knight". The key insight is that if individual $\;x\;$ says $\;P\;$, then $\;T(x) \equiv P\;$.

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Tag}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
\newcommand{\exactly}[4]{\text{exactly one of }#1,#2,#3\text{ is }#4}
$Using this insight, we can formalize the statements of these individuals as follows:
\begin{align}
\tag 1 T(N1) &\;\equiv\; T(N1) \land T(N2) \land T(N3) \\
\tag 2 T(N2) &\;\equiv\; \exactly{T(N1)}{T(N2)}{T(N3)}{\true} \\
\tag 3 T(N3) &\;\equiv\; T(N3) \land \lnot T(N1) \land \lnot T(N2) \\
\end{align}

---

First, we can substitute both $\Tag 1$ and $\Tag 3$:

$$\calc
T(N1)
\calcop\equiv{using $\Tag 1$}
T(N1) \land T(N2) \land T(N3)
\calcop\equiv{using $\Tag 3$}
T(N1) \land T(N2) \land T(N3) \land \lnot T(N1) \land \lnot T(N2)
\calcop\equiv{contradiction (two, actually): $P \land \lnot P \;\equiv\; \false$}
\false
\endcalc$$

In other words, $N1$ is a knave.  Then, we can use this to simplify $\Tag 2$:

$$\calc
\tag 2
T(N2) \;\equiv\; \exactly{T(N1)}{T(N2)}{T(N3)}{\true}
\calcop\equiv{simplify using $\;T(N1) \equiv \false\;$}
T(N2) \;\equiv\; T(N2) \not\equiv T(N3)
\calcop\equiv{simplify using $\;P \equiv P \;\equiv\; \true\;$}
T(N3) \;\equiv\; \false
\endcalc$$

So $N3$ is also a knave.

There is nothing we can say about $N2$: given what we know, it could be either knight or knave.  That is, substituting $\;T(N1) \equiv \false\;$ and $\;T(N3) \equiv \false\;$ in $\Tag 1, \Tag 2, \Tag 3$ makes all three true, regardless of $\;T(N2)\;$.

Comment: I really like this formal approach, and as you say it can be generalized. Thank you very much. @Marnix-Klooster

Comment: @Carlos You're welcome! You also may be interested in [some other answers of mine to related questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+user%3A11994+knave).

Answer (score 0):

this is an clear answer to this problem:
N1 can,t be a knight,because a knight won,t say that he is a knave because that is a lie and he only tell the truth.so N1 is a knave.now,if N3 was a knight,what he is saying is that only i am the knight and other two are knaves,but in this case,N2 would also be a knight, which completely destroys the N3 statement. So N3 can,t be a knight so he is also a knave.and,we have 2 knaves,but we don,t know if the N2 is a knave or not.but if N2 was a knave,N1 would be a knight which leads to a contradiction, so N2 is a knight and this completely make sense.